# Can you update a second variable based on changes to the first in a for loop?

Tags: c

I need two variables to increment, but the second variable depends on the first in this way

```
for (int i = 0, j = i % strlen(user_input); i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
```

Somehow the j variable does not increase; it stays at 0. Advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't do too much inside for loops themselves even if it can be made to work it's very language specific and even in the context of c leads to less readable code

Comment: A variable doesn't track another variable it was initialised from, loop or no loop. It's a variable. You want it to increase, you add code that increases it.

Comment: If, you want to "initialize" a second variable, yes you can. But if you expect `j` to also change as `i` is updated, that is not going to happen. You will have to update `j` at every iteration. That is basics of how variables work in C.

Comment: If you want `j` to track `i`, then add `, j++` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Point to note is `strlen` returns `size_t` and every single iteration calling `strlen` is not for good performance.</sup>

As Ajay said if your intention is to update `j` as `i` changes then you have to write that change explicitly. By simply initializing `j` like that - it won't give you on-the-fly variable which changes as the value of `i` changes.
Example:

```
for (int i = 0, j = i % strlen(user_input); i < strlen(plaintext); i++) {
  ..
  j++; // or any change that you want to have in j like j =i+2
       // j = i%2 
}
```

Also you can update variable `j` based on other variables too - it is just a variable, the condition that changes it's value will be decided by you by writing appropriate code.

To answer your comment

```
   size_t len1 = strlen(user_input);
   size_t len2 = strlen(plaintext);
   for (size_t i = 0, j = i % len1; i < len2; i++) {
      ..
      j++; // or any change that you want to have in j like j =i+2
           // j = i%2 
           // j = i%len1;
    }
```

This ensures that the string length calculation is done once outside the loop. This is done once before the loop starts.

Comment: As for improving the code, how do I go about it? Do I have to store strlen(plaintext) and strlen(user_input) into variables so they don't have to compute every loop?

Comment: my bad, it's my first time asking a question and still new to C. Hard to put code that I want to express into words. Will improve next time

Comment: @coderredoc I agree, the title is quite misleading. But I can't think of anything better as a title.